# Why is Graphics not painting?

Tags: java, 2d, gpu

I searched google for this problem, but i can't really resolve them.

More info on code below.

Here are the two snippets of code, relevant:

```
//prepare
            g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

            for(ListIterator<Chunk> it = chunkvector.listIterator();it.hasNext();){
                Chunk r = it.next();
                r.drawChunk(g);
            }

            for(ListIterator<Entity> it = vectorpainter.listIterator();it.hasNext();){
                Entity r = it.next();
                r.drawObjects(g);
            }
            //Chat

            if(coni.getVerified()){
            try {
                chat.update(g);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                println("I/O Exception while updating chat! "+e.toString());
            }


            //Framerate Anzeige
            if(fps_on){
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawString("FPS: "+fps, 20, 20);
            }
            //Tickberechnung & Anzeige
            tick++;
            if(tick>=65536)
                    tick=0;
            if(tick_on){
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawString("Tick: "+tick,80,20);
            }

            //end drawing
            g.dispose();
            strategy.show();
```

interesting about that:
Chunks, Entities are painted, white rect also, but fps and tick NEVER (both are true, of course), i even wrote System.out.print("..."); into the if-clauses, and it is executed! :S
I think it is something about GPU acceleration, so i added the second code block, how images are loaded. One entity does also drawString, (showing playername above head) and it works, but in the main thread not? :(

second:

```
public Image[] loadPics(String path, int cnt){
    Image[] anim = new Image[cnt];
    BufferedImage source = null;
    BufferedImage temp;

    URL pic_url = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (pic_url == null) {
        fail("Can't find ref: "+path);
    }
    try{
        source = ImageIO.read(pic_url);
    }catch(IOException e){
        fail("Failed to load: "+path);
    }
    // create an accelerated image of the right size to store our sprite in
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

    for(int x=0;x<cnt;x++){
        temp = source.getSubimage(x*source.getWidth()/cnt, 0, 
                source.getWidth()/cnt, source.getHeight());
        anim[x]= gc.createCompatibleImage(temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), Transparency.BITMASK);
        anim[x].getGraphics().drawImage(temp,0,0,null);

    }
    System.out.println(pic_url+" - loaded.");
    return anim;        
}
```

second one i copied from a tutorial, maybe a bit edited.Before that i"ve painted with paintComponent(Graphics g) ... this worked, tutorial have said i could get better performance using this method, so i tried, and want to manage it somehow.
Now it is drawing in a run loop, when i copy everything to paintComponent, no Images are drawn.

For those who managed to get past all the text a little bit of extra work:
The program runs fine on a university pc - not that good hardware ^^ , and bit of laggy at mine, which should be more than double the computationpower. Any ideas? :( 
Java(c) 1.7

Many thanks, even you just read that! :)

Comment: I would "suspect" that the second example isn't working because your draw loop is blocking the EDT.  A fully runnable example that demonstrates your problem or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be more useful

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this can be closed. My drawing problem had nothing to do with the code above.
Problem was, that things i wanted to paint were not in the picture. That I achieved through giving statements like:

```
fillRect(50,50,2/3*frame.getHeight(),130);
```

the 2/3 resolves to 0, multiplied with frameHeight...

Trick was to write (int)(2./3.*frame.getHeight()) 
and one time I also tried to draw a String into the panel section, where closing , maximize buttons are, that wont work too , of course.

THanks anyway!